# REST how to return list of Interface

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a class `FoodItemImpl` which implements the interface `FoodItem`.

I want to return list of `FoodItem` using REST.

**I couldn't**

However, I can return list of `FoodItemImpl` like this:

**Wraper**

```
enum wria {
    instance;
    private Map<Integer, FoodItemImpl> map = new HashMap<Integer, FoodItemImpl>();

    public Map<Integer, FoodItemImpl> get() {
        return this.map;
    }

    wria() {
        List<FoodItem> LL = FoodItemImpl.getAllFoodItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < LL.size(); i++) {
            map.put(LL.get(i).getID(), (FoodItemImpl) LL.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**REST Code**

```
@GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public List<FoodItemImpl> getXML() {
        List<FoodItemImpl> ll = new LinkedList<FoodItemImpl>();
        ll.addAll(wria.instance.get().values());
        return ll;
    }
```

Comment: @acdcjunior i edit the question, I added the code which makes the exception , I added the exception

Comment: I meant starting code of `FoodItem` and `FoodItemImpl`. We need to check the annotations.

Comment: the starting code for `foodItemImpl` is `@Path("/fooditems")`, the `FoodItem` has not annotation

Comment: when is the exception thrown? At the end of the getXML rest method?

Comment: @OliverWatkins I gave you the exception at the end of my question. check it please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error states that you do not have a message body writer for the interface `FoodItem` to the type application/xml. Now, assuming you are using JAXB as default mbw for XML:

**JAXB cannot bind interfaces out of the box**. You have to create an adapter:

```
public class AnyFoodItemAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object,Object> {
    Object unmarshal(Object v) { return v; }
    Object marshal(Object v) { return v; }
}
```

And then annotate FoodItem:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnyFoodItemAdapter .class)
interface FoodItem {
    ...
}
```

See more details and other ways of doing this in: [Project JAXB - Mapping Interfaces](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html).

Comment: I am using Jersy, does that make it difference from ur answer ?

Comment: No, Jersey is the JAX-RS implementor. It must use another framework to convert objects into XML. JAXB is one of such frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating your Interface Getter Methods (JAXB) to define the elements in your result XML. That should resolve your issue, I believe.

Instead of returning List, try having another XmlElement class (Interface if you want) which holds a list for you.

Comment: I don't understant, please would you give an example